# Double a decimal string

Tags: java, arrays, string, double

I am writing my own big integer class in java without imports and need a method for doubling a number of any size that is represented by a string. The code I have for this now works, but begins to take a long time once the numbers get bigger and bigger. I essentially create two arrays: the main array and the countdown array which both start as the same thing. Then, I run a while loop and increment the main array up and increment the countdown array down. When the countdown array reaches "0", I terminate the loop and the result is a new array with the new number doubled in size. Then of course I have if statements checking whether the arrays need to change the ten's place, etc.... here's what I have... Is there any way I can make it more efficient and quick?

```
public static String doubleDecimalString (String main) {
    String countdown = main;    
    String finalBuild = "";
    boolean runLoop = true;

    //if zero is supplied, skip all the nonsense and just return 0
    //else, loop through and find the true double

    //was having trobule getting single digits to double correctly so i had to hard code this for now.
   if (main.equals("0")) {
        return main;
    } else if (main.equals("5")) {
        return "10";
    } else if (main.equals("6")) {
        return "12";
    } else if (main.equals("7")) {
        return "14";
    } else if (main.equals("8")) {
        return "16";
    } else if (main.equals("9")) {
        return "18";
    } else {
        //Array for ORIGINAL NUMBER
        int[] mainPiece = new int[main.length()+2];
        int arrayLength = mainPiece.length;

        for ( int i = 0; i < main.length(); i++ ) {
           mainPiece[i+2] = Integer.parseInt(main.substring( i, i+1));
        }
        mainPiece[0] = -1;
        mainPiece[1] = -1;

        //Array for COUNTDOWN NUMBER
        int[] countdownPiece = new int[main.length()+2];

        for ( int i = 0; i < main.length(); i++ ) {
           countdownPiece[i+2] = Integer.parseInt(main.substring( i, i+1));
        }
        countdownPiece[0] = -1;
        countdownPiece[1] = -1;

        while (  runLoop ) {

            //Increment and decrement the two arrays
            mainPiece[arrayLength-1] += 1;    
            countdownPiece[arrayLength-1] -= 1;        

            //UPDATE MAIN ARRAY
            if (  mainPiece[arrayLength-1] == 10 ) {
                for (int x = arrayLength-1; x > 0; x--) {

                  if ( (mainPiece[x] == 10) && (mainPiece[x-1] != 9) ) {
                        mainPiece[x] = 0;
                        mainPiece[x -1] += 1;
                    } else if ( (mainPiece[x] == 10) && (mainPiece[x-1] == 9) ) {
                        mainPiece[x] = 0;
                        mainPiece[x -1] += 1;    
                        x = arrayLength;
                    } 
                     if ( (mainPiece[2] == 10) ) {
                        mainPiece[1] = 1;
                        mainPiece[2] = 0;
                    }

                }
            } // end main array

          //UPDATE SIDE ARRAY
            if (  countdownPiece[arrayLength-1] == -1 ) {
                for (int x = arrayLength-1; x > 0; x--) {

                   if ( (countdownPiece[x] == -1) && (countdownPiece[x-1] > 0) && (x > 1)  ) {
                        countdownPiece[x] = 9;
                        countdownPiece[x -1] -= 1;
                    } else if ( (countdownPiece[x] == -1) && (countdownPiece[x-1] == 0) && (x > 1) ) {
                        countdownPiece[x] = 9;
                        countdownPiece[x -1] -= 1;    
                        x = arrayLength;
                    }  

                }
            } //end side array


           //tests whether the pieces need to be switched to -1 for scanning
            for (int x = 0; x < arrayLength - 1; x++) {
                  if ( (countdownPiece[x] == -1 ) && (countdownPiece[x+1] == 0 ) ) {
                        countdownPiece[x+1] = -1;
                  }
            }

            //if the side array has reached "0" then the loop will stop and the main array will return the new doubled value
            if ( (countdownPiece[arrayLength-1] == -1) &&  (countdownPiece[arrayLength-2] == -1) )   {
                break;
            }

        } //end while loop

            //transform array into string
            finalBuild = "";      
            for (int T = 0; T < arrayLength; T++) {
                finalBuild += (mainPiece[T] != -1) ? mainPiece[T] : "";
             }
              return finalBuild;
    }           

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this (it basically does a multiply by two and accounts for carries):

```
private String doubleNumber(String number)
{
    int doubleDig = 0;
    int carry = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = number.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        char c = number.charAt(i);
        int origNum = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        doubleDig = origNum * 2 + carry;
        carry = doubleDig / 10;
        doubleDig = doubleDig % 10;

        sb.append(doubleDig);
    }
    if (carry > 0)
    {
        sb.append(carry);
    }

    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Obviously this only handles integers.

Comment: That would be easy to generalize to any single digit multiplication.

Comment: Really helpful curob. Thanks much. I never would have came up with something so simple yet brilliant!

Comment: @Ian This is automating what you would have to do by hand.  Most computer algorithms existed long before there was computers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use StringBuilder or List to build your doubled value.

Use a carry variable to store the carry amount and initialize to 0.

Start at the least significant digit, double the digits and add the carry.

Then set the `carry` to `digit / 10`, then the `digit` to `digit % 10`

Append `digit` to your builder or list.

After you loop through all your digits, check if `carry` is > 0 and append if needed.

Reverse the StringBuilder or list and join and you have your answer.

```
public class Doubler {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(doubleDec("9123123123087987342348798234298723948723987234982374928374239847239487.23233099"));
  }

  public static String doubleDec(String dec) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = dec.length() - 1; i > -1 ; i--) {
      char charDigit = dec.charAt(i);
      if (charDigit == '.') {
        builder.append(charDigit);
      } else {
        int digit = Character.getNumericValue(charDigit);
        if (digit == -1) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid character in decimal string.");
        }
        digit = digit * 2 + carry;
        carry = digit / 10;
        digit = digit % 10;
        builder.append(digit);
      }
    }
    if (carry != 0) {
      builder.append(carry);
    }
    return builder.reverse().toString();
  }
}

// 18246246246175974684697596468597447897447974469964749856748479694478974.46466198
```